# Netbeans 12.2: horizontal scroll not working

Tags: netbeans, horizontal-scrolling, gnome, debian-buster, touchpad

When I'm opening any type of file in Netbeans and I'm trying to horizontally scroll with two fingers from the touchpad, it is not working.

I am using a *MacBook (13 inch, Mid 2010)* with *Debian 10 ("Buster")*, *GNOME 3.30.2* as desktop and *Apache Netbeans 12.2*.

Maybe you know a solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many macOS users often don't restart their IDE for days. Try quitting NetBeans (make sure it doesn't show up on the force quit menu as well; if it does, then just force quit it from there as well). After this, restart your computer and make sure to uncheck the box that asks whether you'd like the OS to re-open your open windows. This should fix the horizontal scrolling issue.

Alternatively, try holding shift and scrolling vertically. This would work best with a mouse with a scroll wheel.

Comment: Thank you very much, adisidev! Indeed, holding down the `SHIFT` button along with vertically scrolling (either from touchpad, or from mouse scroll wheel) did work. I didn't need to restart the IDE or the OS. Good luck to you.

Comment: You're most welcome! Good luck to you as well!